# Projective dimension zero or infinity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring (having unity) with the maximal ideal $m$, which consists only of zero-divisors. Then for any finitely generated $R$-module $M$, the projective dimension $\operatorname{pd}(M)$ of $M$ is zero or infinity.

I am glitched at this problem having searched of help. I would appreciate the solver. Of course, I am aware that as of a left Noetherian ring $S$ for which the $pd(M)$ of any f.g. right module $M$ is zero or infinity, $S$ is a left Kasch ring. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** If there's a module $M$ with $0<\operatorname{pd}(M)<\infty$, then consider a resolution
$$0\to F_m\to F_{m-1}\to\dots\to F_0\to M\to 0$$
of $M$ by finitely generated free modules. Try to prove that the injective map $F_m\to F_{m-1}$ must split and that therefore there's a shorter resolution.

Comment: @user26857: Given the condition on $R$, any injection of free $R$-modules splits. It doesn't matter whether the resolution is minimal.